# Codeigniter - Repopulation Of Input Field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some input fields on my page I would like to be repopulated when saved. The values are entered into the database and I would like those values to be echoed in the input field so that users can see what they have inserted.

**View**

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
 <label>Test1 </label>
<input type="number" name="ft_ca1[]" min="0" max="10" class="form-control input-sm rounded-0" value="<?php echo $student->ft_scores? $student->ft_scores->ft_ca1: 0; ?>">
 </div>
```

**Model**

```
 public function get_student_ftscore($subjectId,$sessionId,$sectionId,$classId,$studentId){
   
         $sql = "SELECT mp.id, mp.student_id, mp.class_id, mp.section_id, mp.ft_ca1, mp.ft_ca2, mp.ft_ca3, mp.ft_ca4, mp.ft_ca5, mp.ft_ca6, mp.ft_project, mp.ft_affective, mp.ft_psychomotor, mp.ft_exam, mp.ft_tot_score, mp.created_at, mp.modified_at
                FROM ftscores_primary mp
                WHERE mp.class_id = ? AND mp.student_id = ? AND mp.section_id = ? AND mp.subject_id = ?  AND mp.session_id = ?
                UNION
                SELECT mt.id, mt.student_id, mt.class_id, mt.section_id, mt.ft_ca1, mt.ft_ca2, mt.ft_ca3, mt.ft_ca4, mt.ft_ca5, mt.ft_ca6, mt.ft_project, mt.ft_affective, mt.ft_psychomotor, mt.ft_exam, mt.ft_tot_score, mt.created_at, mt.modified_at
                FROM ftscores_rn mt
                WHERE mt.class_id = ? AND mt.student_id = ? AND mt.section_id = ? AND mt.subject_id = ? AND mt.session_id = ?";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($classId, $studentId, $sectionId, $subjectId, $sessionId, $classId, $studentId, $sectionId, $subjectId, $sessionId));
        $result = $query->row();
        return $result;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
   public function GetClassStudentsForSubjectft()
    {
        $class_id = $this->input->post('class_id');

        $section_id = $this->input->post('section_id');
        
        $subject_id = $this->input->post('subject_id');
        
        $data['class_id'] = $class_id;

        $data['subject_id'] = $subject_id;

        $data['section_id'] = $section_id;

        $data['subjects'] = $this->subject_model->getAll();

        $class = $this->class_model->get();

        $data['classlist'] = $class;

        $data['session_name'] = $this->setting_model-> getCurrentSessionName();

        $session_id = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession();

        $students = $this->student_model->GetClassStudentsForSubjectft($session_id, $class_id, $section_id);
        
        $data['students'] = [];
        if(!empty($subject_id)){
            foreach($students as $student){
                $ftscore = $this->ftprimary_model->get_student_ftscore($subject_id,$session_id,$section_id,$class_id,$student->student_id);
                
                $student->ftscores = $ftscore;
                $data['students'][] = $student;

            }
        }
```

Comment: please show your problem with screenshoot??

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a session to save the array with the data that was entered and then redirect back to the initial page after the data was succesful saved in the database. You should check if your codeigniter version has the notion of the flash message. This is used to save some data just for on page and after is deleted.  Then in your form you will check if the data is set and not null, if is set then echo it. If you are just learning, i will recomend you to start learning codeigniter 4.